# C# Infinite Nested DataList

Tags: c#, asp.net, nested-datalist

I have a relatively simple question about nested *DataList*.

How to dynamically nest infinite DataLists?

I didn't write any code yet, because I don't know how, but follow is an example:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
            <br />
            <asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
</div>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</form>
```

There are no problems when we have limited levels depth, we just nest two or three levels on *DataList* and we are done. But when we don't have a defined levels depth.

When the button clicked it loads the DataList2, when DataList2 button is clicked and it should load DataList3 and so far. And repeat it every time I click the button inside a *DataList*.

e.g.

```
-DatalistOUTER
--Some bindings
--Button [clicked]
[loads]
----DatalistINNER
-----Some bindings
-----Button [clicked]
[loads]
------DatalistINNERINNER
-------Somebindings
-------Button
```

Comment: This question appears too general to be easily answered.

Comment: This isn't a relative(ly) simple question. I think you need to try to explain it better and to show the code that you've written. You should read [ask] and [mcve].